# How can I prove that the derivative of a piecewise function $f$ is unbounded on the interval $[-1, 1]$?

Tags: functions

The function $f(x):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ can be defined as:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
         x-x^2\cos(\pi/x^2), & \text{if } x \neq 0 \newline
         0, & \text{if } x = 0
       \end{cases}$$

Prove that the derivative $f'(x)$ is not bounded on the interval $[-1,1]$.

So far i have found that:
$$f'(x) = \begin{cases}
         1-2x\cos(\pi/x^2)-2\pi (\sin(\pi/x^2))/x, & \text{if } x \neq 0 \newline
         1, & \text{if } x = 0
       \end{cases}$$

I tried finding the limit: $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x)$ or $\lim_{x \to 0^-} f'(x)$, but they seem undefined and I can't find any other way to prove $f'(x)$ is not bounded.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that the derivative of the function $f$ is unbounded on the interval $[−1,1]$, we need to show that for any $M>0$, there exists an $x$ in the interval $[−1,1]$ such that $|f'(x)|>M$.

First, note that the derivative of $$ is continuous everywhere except at $x=0$. Therefore, we only need to consider the behavior of the derivative near $x=0$.

Let $M$ be any positive number. Consider a sequence of points x_n = 1/√(2n+1) for $n=1, 2, 3, ....$ It can be shown that this sequence approaches zero as n approaches infinity, and all points $x_n$ are within the interval $[−1,1]$.

Now, we will show that $|f'(x_n)|>M$ for all $n$. We have:

\begin{equation*}
f'(x_n) = 1 - 2x_n\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x_n^2}\right) - \frac{2\pi\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{x_n^2}\right)}{x_n}
\end{equation*}
The second term on the right-hand side can be bounded using the inequality $| \sin \theta | \leq \theta$for all $θ$. Therefore, we have:

\begin{align*}
|f'(x_n)| &= |1-2x_n\cos(\pi/x_n^2)-2\pi(\sin(\pi/x_n^2))/x_n| \\
&\geq |1 - 2x_n\cos(\pi/x_n^2)| - |2\pi(\sin(\pi/x_n^2))/x_n| \\
&\geq 1 - 2x_n - 2\pi/\sqrt{2n+1}
\end{align*}

The last inequality follows from the fact that $cos(\frac{\pi}{x_n^2})$ is always between $-1$ and $1$.

Now, we just need to choose an appropriate value of n such that |′(x_n)|>M. Let N be any positive integer such that √(2N+1) > 2/M. Then we have:

$$x_N = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2N+1}} < \frac{\pi}{M}$$

Therefore, we can choose N such that both inequalities hold, and we get:

$$\left|f'(x_N)\right| > 1 - 2x_N - \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{2N+1}} > 1 - \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{2N+1}} > M$$

This shows that for any $M>0$, there exists an x in the interval $[−1,1] $ such that $|f'(x)|>M$, and hence the derivative of $f$ is unbounded on the interval $[−1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $1/x$ is unbounded so is $(\sin(\pi/x^2))/x$ (since $\sin x$ is bounded) and so is $1-2x\cos(\pi/x^2)-2\pi (\sin(\pi/x^2))/x$ (since $1-2x\cos(\pi/x^2)$ is bounded).